# How to change constraint of textfield programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

i have menu icon and text field. When textFieldDidBeginEditing method called, i want to hide menu icon and change textfield's position to safe area top. I have connected textfield's top with menu icon. So i need to add constant with safe area programmatically.
Thanks.

Comment: Is Menu icon top is with safe area??

Comment: Please put screen shot icon with textfield

Comment: @dahiya_boy yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the outlet of `heightConstraint` of menu icon and set it zero. On `textview endediting` set it on its `default` position.

**How it Works:**

Before textView began editing

```
textView.top(w.r.t safearea) = textView.top(w.r.t menu button) + btnmenu.height + btnMenu.top (w.r.t safearea)
```

After textView began editing as `btnmenu.height = 0`

```
textView.top(w.r.t safearea) = textView.top(w.r.t menu button) +  btnMenu.top (w.r.t safearea)
```

**Diametric Explanation:**

- Left : Before textView began editing
- Right : After textView began editing as `btnmenu.height = 0`

[image]

**Note :** You can take outlet of constraints of `BtnMenu.top` & `BtnMenu.bottom` and set them as per your need.

Hope now you will be cleared.